# missed workspace manager on Version: 0.2.1 "Luna" ( 32-bit )

Tags: luna, window-manager, plank

Hi can anyone help please

have on different machines installed elementary OS
 but unfortunately  on this one it doesn't work and cant find a Workspace manager

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Luna, workspaces are only accessible with a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or by setting up hot corners. The multitasking view (and its shortcut) was added in Freya.

As an aside, Luna (0.2.x) no longer receives updates from elementary. You should upgrade to the latest release (0.3.2) to continue receiving updates from elementary.

Comment: Since Freya doesn't work properly on some older hardware where Luna worked perfectly (e.g. Intel Atom or Core2Duo where Luna was *the best*) it's no surprise some folks don't want to upgrade and stick to Luna with only Ubuntu updates (which will roll until 2017).